Is "Pawn Pugilism" won for White or Black?
There might be another established word in English (in German it's "Bauernkloppe") for this training lesson for kids, but the rules are simple: Both sides have only the pawns at their usual places, first one to queen wins. (Stalemate rarely happens and is a draw.)
Is this a win for white or black? (My own verdict: Nearly as hard as "normal" chess. Thus I would be surprised about an actual proof, but someone might have built a tablebase already.)
BTW, 4 against 4 is won for White, just enter 1k6/1P2pppp/KP6/PP6/8/8/4PPPP/8 in your engine. (I did when researching and published it as a #11 chess problem.)

Apparently 5 vs. 5 is likewise won for White
(k7/P2ppppp/Kp6/bP6/1p6/1P6/3PPPPP/8 b - - 0 1).

@NoamD.Elkies: The setup is somewhat unfair for Black, as he loses even if he queens before White. Bk6/1P1ppppp/1P6/8/8/1p6/1p1PPPPP/bK6 w - - 0 1 is a draw (1.e4! g5! only moves - or 1.g4 e5 which is the same.)

Ah, good point -- I did wonder if this figured into the evaluation.  FWIW it seems this can be done without Bishops: k7/Pp1ppppp/1P6/8/8/1p6/pP1PPPPP/K7

Just to clarify - players have or don't have kings?

@MatijaSirk the players don't have kings. The point of the example in the OP (which also confused me at first) is to give a position with kings which is equivalent to 4 pawns versus 4 pawns with no kings, first to queen wins, so that it can be evaluated with a chess engine (since the chess engine will not accept a kingless position).

@Flounderer: Exactly. Although P.P. can (and will) be played with kings by advanced kids. This literarily changes the rules.
